# Possible Memory Issue with WinAPI ListView

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I'm creating a SQL client with **WinAPI**. Every time a user submits a query, the current columns and items of my `ListView` are deleted, then new columns and items are created based on the results of the query.

I've noticed through `Visual Studio` heap profiler, that every time the columns and items are created, **3 objects and ~60 bytes** are allocated, and I can't figure out why. Examining the snapshot suggests this has to do with adding SubItems via the `ListView_SetItem` function (`_ListView_OnSetItem` is the last thing I can identify in Stacks View).

**The results I'm using to test with create 4 columns and 36 items/subitems.**

To the best of my knowledge, I've implemented the `ListView` stuff correctly. Still, here are my two functions that reset and populate the `ListView`. Any help  is appreciated.

```
void ResetListView(HWND hWnd) {

    HWND hWndHdr = (HWND)SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDQ_LISTVIEW), LVM_GETHEADER, 0, 0);
    int numColumns = (int)SendMessage(hWndHdr, HDM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0L);

    ListView_DeleteAllItems(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDQ_LISTVIEW));
    for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++)
        ListView_DeleteColumn(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDQ_LISTVIEW), 0);
}

void CreateListView(HWND hWnd, QueryResults * queryResults) {

    LVCOLUMN lvc;
    ZeroMemory(&lvc, sizeof(LVCOLUMN));
    lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
    lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_CENTER;

    int numHeaders = queryResults->numHeaders;

    // Add columns
    for (int i = 0; i < numHeaders; i++) {
        lvc.iSubItem = i;
        lvc.pszText = queryResults->headers[i];
        lvc.cx = 100;
        ListView_InsertColumn(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDQ_LISTVIEW), i, (LPARAM)&lvc);
    }

    LVITEM lvi;
    ZeroMemory(&lvi, sizeof(LVITEM));
    lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;

    // Add items and subitems
    for (int i = 0; i < queryResults->rows.size(); i++) {
        lvi.iItem = i;

        lvi.pszText = queryResults->rows[i]->cells[0];
        lvi.iSubItem = 0;
        ListView_InsertItem(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDQ_LISTVIEW), (LPARAM)&lvi);

        for (int j = 1; j < numHeaders; j++) {
            lvi.pszText = queryResults->rows[i]->cells[j];
            lvi.iSubItem = j;
            ListView_SetItem(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDQ_LISTVIEW), (LPARAM)&lvi);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong there, so the error must be somewhere else. Are you doing custom draw in your listview? See if you can create a [MCVE].

Comment: @JonathanPotter Nope, I'm not using custom draw with my ListView. Making a minimal version of my program sounds like a good course of action. I'll try that out.

Comment: You might consider using a [virtual ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/use-virtual-list-view-controls) instead so you don't have to make a copy of the result data in the ListView itself at all, you can display data directly from your result set. That will eliminate any memory overhead that the ListView would normally use internally

Comment: Also, consider saving the header control handle rather than making multiple GetDlgItem calls. Either that or use SendDlgItemMessage (which takes a child window ID as an additional parameter). The downside to SendDlgItemMessage is that it can't be used with the windowsx.h macros.

Comment: @J.S.B. why do you think this allocation is wrong or a problem in a first place?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, why is that useful to save header handle?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Good idea, I'll take a look at that. Thanks!

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Good idea, thanks!

Comment: @bunglehead - Granted, 60 additional bytes every time the ListView is remade is not much, but it still seems like a memory leak. I wondered if someone more familiar with ListViews or WinAPI in general might have an explanation or could point out a flaw with my functions.

Comment: @J.S.B. turn on the [RTL's memory leak detector](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown). If it does not detect a leak, the problem is not in your code, it is in the OS itself, so you should not worry about it, let the OS deal with it

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I just ran it with Visual Leak Detector and it wasn't able to detect any memory leaks, so I think you're right. I'll leave it to the OS to deal with. Thanks!

Comment: @J.S.B. yes, sorry, my bad, I didn't pay attention to which compiler you were using, so I gave you the wrong link to read.